# How to work with django template variable and javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a django template variable `{% clients_list %}`
I want to load this in multiple select boxes with same prefixes.
I am writing this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (i=1; i<=30; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=clients_list.length - 1; j++){
            $('#client'+i).append($('<option>')
            .text(clients_list[j])
            .attr('value', clients_list[j]));
            }
        }
    });
```

But I am facing this error:

```
ReferenceError: clients_list is not defined
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, [encode as JSON](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/201/).

```
{% load jsonify %}

var clients_list = {{ clients_list|jsonify }};
```

Comment: Just found that, this too works:
`var clients_list = {{ clients_list|safe }};`

Comment: @MHS: Python's list representation is not the same as JSON.